What did they do in Old English when using the instead of an?
I know that in Old English the would place n infront of words that start with a vowel after saying the word a but did they still do it when they said the? For example would a napron stay as the napron or would it become the apron?

You’re misunderstanding how it worked. Originally, the indefinite article was just a reduced version of the number ‘one’, so it always had an n at the end. Later on, that n was lost except before vowel sounds. The definite article is different in that it never had an n in the base (nominative) form. But note that you’re not talking about Old English here – OE didn’t really have an indefinite article at all, and the definite article sē had lots of different forms. An and the are Middle and Modern English.

This question is similar to: Why did the Rebracketing from "Napron" to "Apron" Figuratively Stick?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
